# postgres match with regex

Tags: regex, postgresql, psql

I have a column containing values like this

```
views.decorators.cache.cache_header.APISetOne.596e986edcf211a323dbac38fe3654b8.en-us.UTC
views.decorators.cache.cache_page.APISetTwo.GET.1fc365e1f67d39935b199c133fada23b.ce596bddd33104b703521c71eb2e32c6.en-us.UTC
```

It is something like 'view.decorators.cache.cache_{page|header}.{if header then None in this part, if not 'GET'}.**{key_prefix_name}**.*{some_hash_that changes_everytime}*.**{last_hash}**.en-us.UTC' #i don't care about en-us.UTC thing.

I have access to key_prefix_name and the last_hash.

I want to search across rows that contains a particular key_prefix_name and the last_hash.

I am struggling to create a regex that matches this. So far, I have come up with something like:

```
select col1 from my_table where col1 ~* 'views.decorators.cache.cache_page.**APISetOne**.GET.[a-z,1-0].**ce596bddd33104b703521c71eb2e32c6**.en-us.UTC';
```

Comment: Something like `views\.decorators\.cache\.cache_(?:page\.APISetOne\.GET|header)\.([[:alnum:]]+)\.([[:alnum:]]+)\.en-us\.UTC`? Or maybe `views\.decorators\.cache\.cache_(?:page|header)\.([[:alnum:]]+)\.(?:GET\.)?([[:alnum:].]+)\.en-us\.UTC`? What are the expected results?

Comment: A good place to begin would be the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-matching.html).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks it worked without the "\" before each dot though, I ended up with something like 'views.decorators.cache.cache_page.THE_PREFIX.GET.([[:alnum:]]+).THE_LAST_HASH.en-us.UTC' Thanks for helping me out with that alnum part, I suck at regex

Comment: You need to escape the `.`, or it will match any char. Have a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/YwGPjm/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use

```js
views\.decorators\.cache\.cache_(?:page|header)\.([[:alnum:]]+)\.(?:GET\.)?([[:alnum:]]+)(?:\.[[:alnum:]]+)?\.en-us\.UTC
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YwGPjm/2). It matches

- `views\.decorators\.cache\.cache_` - a fixed `views.decorators.cache.cache_` string
- `(?:page|header)` - `page` or `header`
- `\.` - a dot
- `([[:alnum:]]+)` - Group 1: one or more alphanumerics
- `\.` - a dot
- `(?:GET\.)?` - an optional `GET.` string
- `([[:alnum:]]+)` - Group 2: one or more alphanumerics
- `(?:\.[[:alnum:]]+)?` - an optional occurrence of a `.` and then one or more alphanumeric char sequence
- `\.en-us\.UTC` - a `.en-us.UTC` string.

Comment: Yes, I added the backslash and it works, I am executing this from python so, I must have had some typo before I guess. And, thanks for the detailed answer, I seem to understand some now. I appreciate it, thank you!